# Summer '19 Community timeout bug

Tags: customer-community, summer19

Has anyone else experienced this bug?

1. Log into your summer '19 customer community.
2. Let the session timeout (create a profile that has a 15 minute timeout to test)
3. Log back into the community.

The resulting page is "not found" and has access to user profile settings that can be unchecked in the community builder.

We are using a Customer Community Plus user license.

Here's a screenshot of the page that appears when you login after timeout, the yellow box shows options we've disabled in the community.
[image: screenshot of community error page after timeout bug]

Comment: What do you mean by "access to user profile settings that can be unchecked in the community builder."  Can you post a screenshot?  What Customer Community  license are you using?

Comment: Salesforce responded to my case that this is a known issue in Summer '19

Answer (score 0):

Here is a workaround. If you add your full community base path (including the /s/) into "Logout Page URL" Under Community Workspaces -> Administration -> Login & Registration. Your users will not have the session variables appended to the URL when the user times out causing them to go to the "page not found".

Salesforce is continuing to work on the issue.